# How do I update my Angular Table dataSource with data from an Observable

Tags: angular, observable, datasource, mat-table, angular-changedetection

Im trying to display data in my Angular Material Table, that I receive from my backend.

Everything works fine as long as my _timelogService.getAllTimelogs() function returns an Observable of dummy data which I hard coded into the function. As soon as I make an actualy HTTP POST request to my backend - and return an Observable of that data - the html table doesnt display any rows eventhough my dataSource contains the required data.

When I use `logData()` it display the correct data even if i use the actual Observable.

I suspect that my Angular Table does not get updated when the dataSource gets updated.

Did anyone else ever encounter such an issue?

```
export class OverviewComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['roomId', 'startTime', 'endTime', 
  'duration'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<TimeLogTable>();

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;  

  constructor(private _timelogService: TimelogService) {
    //In the Docs example the dummy data gets created here
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._timelogService.getAllTimelogs().subscribe(
      dataObs=>{
        console.log("Display received data");
        console.log(dataObs);
        this.dataSource.data = dataObs;
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      }
    )
  }

  logData(){
    console.log(this.dataSource);
  }
}
```

My Service

```
getAllTimelogs(): Observable<TimeLogTable[]>{
  var timelogsArr: TimeLogTable[] = [];
  var timelogsArrDummy: TimeLogTable[] = [];

  //Call to backend
  this._http.get<any>('http://localhost:3000/gettimelogs?token=' + 
  localStorage.getItem('token'), this.httpOptions)
  .subscribe(
    res=>{
      //Create timeLogTable from json with backend response
      for (let i = 0; i < res.timelogs.length; i++) {
        timelogsArr.push({
          roomId: res.timelogs[i].roomId,
          startTime: new Date(res.timelogs[i].startTime),
          endTime: new Date (res.timelogs[i].endTime), 
          duration: "test"
        });
      }
    },
    err=>{
      //Error handling
    }
  );
  //Return the Observable - DOES NOT WORK
  return of (timelogsArr);

  /*
  //Return the dummy data as an Observable - DOES WORK
  //Dummy data
  timelogsArrDummy = [
  {roomId: 'kit_A', startTime: new Date(1631185600000), endTime: new 
  Date (1631185661311), duration: "test"},
  {roomId: 'din_A', startTime: new Date(1631185600000), endTime: new 
  Date (1631195661311), duration: "test"},
  {roomId: 'off_A', startTime: new Date(1631185600000), endTime: new 
  Date (1632185661311), duration: "test"},
  {roomId: 'kit_B', startTime: new Date(1631185600000), endTime: new 
  Date (1631885661311), duration: "test"},
  ]
  return of (timelogsArrDummy);
  */
}
```

Here a screenshot from the `console.log(dataObs)`:
[image]

Comment: It is probably worth noting that although the data does not get displayed in the html when I call console.log(this.datasource) the data is there. So it must be some sort of update problem right?

Comment: Did you try to `console.log(dataObs)`  and see the output that data is returned? You may also attach the source code for `TimelogService` and the response data to the question.

Comment: I added the missing information as you requested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue that was causing my problem.
My getAllTimelogs() function returned an empty Object first and then filled it up with data later. The MatTableDataSource somehow could not handle that. Here is my working code:

```js
export class OverviewComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['roomId', 'startTime', 'endTime', 'duration'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<TimeLogTable>();

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;  
  
  constructor(private _timelogService: TimelogService) { }

  timelogsArr: TimeLogTable[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._timelogService.getAllTimelogs().subscribe(
      res=>{
        //Create timeLogTable from json with backend response
        console.log("alert");
        for (let i = 0; i < res.timelogs.length; i++) {
          //Change the format of the data
          this.timelogsArr.push({
            roomId: res.timelogs[i].roomId,
            startTime: new Date(res.timelogs[i].startTime),
            endTime: new Date (res.timelogs[i].endTime), 
            duration: this.msToTime(res.timelogs[i].endTime - res.timelogs[i].startTime)
          });
        }
        //Update table datasource
        this.dataSource.data = this.timelogsArr;
      }
    );
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

And here the `getAlltimelogs()` function:

```js
getAllTimelogs(): Observable<any>{
    return this._http.get<any>('http://localhost:3000/gettimelogs?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token'), this.httpOptions)
  }
```

Thanks to everyone who kindly helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You should trigger change detection just after the new data has been received.

```
export class OverviewComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    
      displayedColumns: string[] = ['roomId', 'startTime', 'endTime', 'duration'];
      tableData: any = [];

      dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<TimeLogTable>(this.tableData);
    
      @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
      @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;  
      
      constructor(private _timelogService: TimelogService, private _cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {  }
    
      ngAfterViewInit() {
        this._timelogService.getAllTimelogs().subscribe(
        (dataObs: any)=> {
          this.dataSource.data = dataObs;
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
          this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

          this._cd.detectChanges(); 
        });
        
      }
}
```

Please note, if the data source is being altered in the client-side, it is advisable to call `renderRows()` method instead of triggering change detection.

Comment: So I tried your code snippet but it still doesnt load any data into the html table.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You need to pass the data object to the `MatTableDataSource` during creation of `dataSource` as `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<TimeLogTable>(this.tableData);` Also illustrated in the [official docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#observable-stream-of-data-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

I never used this table but the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#1-write-your-mat-table-and-provide-data) say :

> Since the table optimizes for performance, it will not automatically check for changes to the data array. Instead, when objects are added, removed, or moved on the data array, you can trigger an update to the table's rendered rows by calling its renderRows() method.

So I guess you just have to call this method after your data is loaded.

To call the method you need to add a ViewChild reference to the table:

```html
<table #myTable mat-table ... >
```

Then add:

```js
@ViewChild(MatTable) myTable!: MatTable<any>;
```

And after the data is loaded just call `this.myTable.renderRows();`

Comment: I added the renderRows() function to my  .subscribe() function and the ViewChild reference to my class but the data unfortunately still does not get loaded into my html table.

Answer (score 0):

I followed below approach and its working for me, you can have a try-

In store:

```
private userBehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
  private userApiBehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  private users$: Observable<User[]> = this.userBehaviorSubject.asObservable();
  private usersApi$: Observable<UserApi> = this.userApiBehaviorSubject.asObservable();

  constructor(private readonly userService: UserService
  ) {
  }

/*  loadUsersApi(url: string): void {
    this.userService.getUsersApi(url).subscribe(userApi => {this.userApiBehaviorSubject.next(userApi);
    });
  }*/

  loadUsers(url: string): void {
    this.userService.getUsersApi(url).subscribe(userApi => {
      this.userBehaviorSubject.next(userApi.items);
      this.userApiBehaviorSubject.next(userApi);
    });
  }

  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.users$;
  }

  getUserApi(): Observable<UserApi> {
    return this.usersApi$;
  }
```

in your get api function definitions or UserService

```
getUsersApi(url: string): Observable<UserApi> {
    if (!url){
      url = urlConstants.usersListGetUrl;
    }
    /**
     * Pass the URL parameters, prepare get URL, http method
     */
    this.options = {
      url, // urlConstants.usersListGetUrl,
      method: httpMethod.GET
    } as RestOptions;
    /**
     * Invoke the rest service for get
     */
    return this.invokeRest.invokeRest(this.options)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleErrorService.handleError<any>('getUsersApi'))
      );
  }
```

Your TS:

```
import {UserStore} from '../../store/user-store';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {User} from '../../model/user/user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-list',
  templateUrl: './user-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-list.component.scss']
})
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['userid', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email'];

  users$: Observable<User[]>;
  usersApi$: Observable<UserApi>;

  isNext: boolean;
  isPrevious: boolean;
  isFirst: boolean;

  constructor(private userStore: UserStore,
              private userService: userService
              ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userStore.loadUsers(null);
    this.usersApi$ = this.userStore.getUserApi();
    this.users$ = this.userStore.getUsers();
    this.enableButtons();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

this may be a little late but I do it like this:

my data source is this array:

```
this.myDataSource?: any[];
```

To refresh the info I simply do this after it's been modified

```
this.myDataSource = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.myDataSource));
```

Seems like the not refreshing issue comes from a reference factor.